# Best way to use javascript api for a desktop app

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

i have a desktop application and i really want to use some APIs that are only available in their Javascript version.... (Waze API/Google Earth API), 
my question ... what is the best way if you think its possbile and worth it to perform this bridge between my C# desktop app with this javascript API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute JScript from C#.  Add a reference to Microsoft.JScript and use something like this:

```
using Microsoft.JScript;
object result = Microsoft.JScript.Eval.JScriptEvaluate("my javascript code", Microsoft.JScript.Vsa.VsaEngine.CreateEngine());
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript is not adapted for desktop applications. You could use a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) to embed some web page widget which will execute the javascript.